# Cannot find ado.net entity data model in visual studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, visual-studio-2022, database-first

I want to start a new project in ASP.NET core MVC web application. In the past I'm used to starting with the code, I create the code and I create the dbContext and I make the migration of the data Add-Migration and Update_Migration and finally I can get my database. This time I want to start with the database first, I loaded SSMS(SQL server management studio) and created the database and after I want to generate the classes from the database but It didn't work, I cannot find the ado.net entity data model in visual studio 2022.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem by myself, I added these packages(in the picture below) but also it didn't work

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking for the reverse engineer tools, not the ADO.NET Entity Model. That was an obsolete tool from the early Entity Framework days (2010-ish) used to create an XML model from which both the application and database were built. For EF Core, check the [Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) docs and the [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) extension for Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It worked in the first time but after when I tried to make another exemple It disappeared , When I click on the list I cannot find It